# Proving simple bound on coupon collector

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms

I came across this [paper](https://books.google.com/books?id=-mzTGfO-fkUC&pg=PA451&lpg=PA451&dq=coupon%20collector%20bound%20U1&source=bl&ots=vSSMr85-0E&sig=V4cL23WK7MPgut6Li7PBZYoP7z4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBGoVChMI7vuL74qMyAIVkBSSCh14egZT#v=onepage&q=coupon%20collector%20bound%20U1&f=false) which gives bounds on coupon colloector problem. Page 451 contains a table where reference to U1 is given as 'folklore'. I presume this is trivial to follow from the definition but I can't see the logic behind this. Does anyone have hints for me? I tried to get this bound by taking the limit of probability that some coupon is not found after n tries but that needs n to be infinity.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it self-contained?  What's U1?  If that's an equation, please provide the equation and all necessary definitions in the question.  Also, can you add a full reference to the paper (title, authors, where published), so that if the link stops working, it will still be possible to tell what paper you're referring to?

Comment: Also, this seems to be a question purely about probability, which would be better suited to [math.se].

Comment: It seems like a question about analysis of randomized algorithms.

Comment: @Louis It's a question about a piece of mathematics that's used to analyse randomized algorithms. But the question itself is purely about the mathematics and has nothing to do with its applications to CS.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the process into $n$ phases. The $m$th phase ($m=1,\ldots,n$) starts when the $(m-1)$st cell has been occupied, and ends when the $m$th cell has been occupied. The first phase takes time $1$. Suppose that the occupied cell is $i_1$. The second phase then takes expected time $1/(1-p_{i_1})$. Suppose that the occupied cell is $i_2$. The third phase then takes expected time $1/(1-p_{i_1}-p_{i_2})$. And so on. Overall, the expected time is
$$
1 + \frac{1}{1-p_{i_1}} + \frac{1}{1-p_{i_1}-p_{i_2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{1-p_{i_1}-\cdots-p_{i_{n-1}}} = \\
\frac{1}{p_{i_1}+\cdots+p_{i_n}} + \frac{1}{p_{i_2}+\cdots+p_{i_n}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{p_{i_n}} \leq = \\
\frac{1}{np_1} + \frac{1}{(n-1)p_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{p_1} = \\
\frac{H_n}{p_1} \leq \frac{\ln n + 1}{p_1}.
$$